# Syntax error creating a foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying to create the following tables design but I am getting this error below how can I set the foreign key for the `stops` table  in the `arrivaltimes` table?

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES stops(stop_id) )' at line 4

```
stt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stops"
        + "(stop_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, "
        + " name varchar(30) NOT NULL, " + " route INT(11) NOT NULL, "
        + " lat double(10,6) NOT NULL, "
        + " longi double(10,6)NOT NULL) ");

stt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS arrivaltimes(id INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"
        + " weekday VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,"
        + "arrivaltime time NOT NULL,"
        + " stop_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES stops(stop_id) )" );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```sql
stop_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES stops(stop_id)
```

to

```sql
stop_id INT, FOREIGN KEY fk_stop_id(stop_id) REFERENCES stops(stop_id)
```

Comment: @MrPencil: it looks like a constraint name, and I don't know that it's necessary, but the comma sure is necessary. What happens if you just leave out fk_stop_id?

Comment: MySQL will generate a name if you don't assign one. If you would ever like to drop the foreign key (for example in a schema rollback script), you'll need to specify the name. So it's a good idea to assign it yourself.

Comment: @Hovercraft: if I leave it, it does not work and for the comma is the same

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the query, please take note of the syntax of the FOREIGN KEY, where you had an error. Cheers!

```
stt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stops"
        + "(stop_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, "
        + " name varchar(30) NOT NULL, " + " route INT(11) NOT NULL, "
        + " lat double(10,6) NOT NULL, "
        + " longi double(10,6)NOT NULL) ");



stt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS arrivaltimes(id INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"
                            + " weekday VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,"
                            + "arrivaltime time NOT NULL,"
                            + " FOREIGN KEY (stop_id) REFERENCES stops(stop_id) )" );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [MySQL `CREATE TABLE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html), then you have the choice between:

An inline definition (note the absence of `FOREIGN KEY`)

```sql
stop_id INT REFERENCES stops(stop_id)
```

and an explicit definition:

```sql
stop_id INT,
FOREIGN KEY (stop_id) REFERENCES stops(stop_id)
```

or better (with named constraint):

```sql
stop_id INT,
CONSTRAINT fk_arrivaltimes_stops FOREIGN KEY (stop_id) REFERENCES stops(stop_id)
```